# Segmenting a human body point cloud into limbs

Tags: algorithms, computer-vision, graphics

I have a human body point cloud taken through a Kinect (v1). Now, I want to segment the point cloud into different parts, namely hands, lower arms, upper arms, torso, upper legs, lower legs, feet and head.

Here's the method I'm currently using:

- I get the approximate skeleton from the point cloud using OpenNI
- I take those points from the point cloud that are at a distance **d** from the line that is the bone (obtained from OpenNI). This distance **d** is currently set differently for different parts, based on observations only.

The problem with the above method is that it's not very robust. The parameter **d** can be different for people with different body types and also this is prone to errors since at the joints, the points within the circle of radius **d** will lie in both the parts.

Is there a better way of segmenting the point cloud?

---

**Edit:** This is what I get from OpenNI

[image]

The blue portion is the lower arms segmented using the above algorithm.

Comment: The green lines inside the point cloud, is that from OpenNI? Can't you use joints to discriminate body parts?

Comment: @cagirici yes, those green lines are bones of the skeleton from OpenNI. OpenNI has this `getLimb()` method that gives me one particular bone corresponding to a limb

Comment: The white part is the point cloud and I need the part of the point cloud that corresponds to a particular limb.

Comment: What distance measures of points vs lines have you tried? There are several.

Comment: Just the perpendicular point-line distance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion: for each point $P$ in the point cloud, find which bone it is nearest to, and associate it with that bone.  In other words, find which point $Q$ on the skeleton is closest to $P$, and associate $P$ with $Q$.  Now associate $Q$ with a particular part of the skeleton (e.g., arm, leg, etc.); that will let you associate $P$ with a particular part of body (e.g., arm, leg, etc.).  Do this for each point in the point cloud.

Try that -- it's a very simple approach, and it might just work.

Comment: This is way easier and more accurate: http://imgur.com/fldeugJ Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 1):

I would try the following:

**for** **each** joint $j$:

1. $p_1 \gets$ closest extreme point to $j$ in direction $\vec{d}$
2. $p_2 \gets$ closest extreme point to $j$ in direction $-\vec{d}$
3. Draw vector $\vec{p_1p_2}$
4. Let $\vec{N}, -\vec{N}$ be two normal vectors of $\vec{p_1p_2}$
5. Draw two rays $a_1$, $a_2$ in the direction of $\vec{N}$ and $-\vec{N}$ respectively.
6. Let $i_1$ and $i_2$ be the points belong to another area (such as gray area or another body part) which are closest to the origin of $a_1$ and $a_2$ respectively.
7. $p_3 \gets$ closest extreme point to $i_1$ in direction $\vec{f}$
8. $p_4 \gets$ closest extreme point to $i_1$ in direction $-\vec{f}$
9. $p_5 \gets$ closest extreme point to $i_2$ in direction $-\vec{g}$
10. $p_6 \gets$ closest extreme point to $i_2$ in direction $-\vec{g}$
11. Mark the area $(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5, p_6)$ as body part.

I am not familiar with KINECT nor OPENNI, but given the green circles, representing joints, I would use above algorithm.

Comment: Can you illustrate via a figure? Also, what's $d$, $f$ and $g$ here?

Comment: They are the vectors perpendicular to the green line connecting two green dots.

Comment: Oh, so you're basically trying to create a bounding box between the two joints and getting the points which are in it, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: @ranveer indeed, that is my solution

Comment: That seems way better than what I was using. Plus, if I can find the extreme points, that can make the bounding box size adjust for changes in body type. I'm going to keep the question open for a while, for other answers, though I doubt I'll find something as simple and accurate as this :)

Comment: While the algorithm you stated here was great, the one answered by D.W. is simpler and more accurate (I was losing some points at the elbows from your algorithm). Thanks for your help :)